# How to disable mouseMoved event in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop-application

I'm new in libgdx and I'm trying to create a 2D game.
I want to generate an action when I press a key, that's working perfectly with the render() method.

However, when I'm moving the mouse on the desktop, the render() method is called and my action is generated.

So my question is : How to disable mouseMoved event for don't call the render() method when I move the mouse ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code, how you generate Action when you press key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply Override the mouseMoved method, and do nothing in it (leave an empty body).